# How would I extract data from one website and put it into mine?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Chrome Extension that will show me my grades in school. They put these grades on a website and they are always in a chart. I have [selector gadget](https://selectorgadget.com/), but I'm not really sure how I can use it.

At first I tried `document.getElementById().innerhtml` but couldn't figure out how to replace `<p>` text with my grades. Then I read up on PHP and stuff like that but I really can't do anything like that. i need it all to be in Javascript (at least I think that's what Google Chrome Extensions allow).

Here's where I'm a so far:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <style>
    .default {

    }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <p class="default">art: </p>

    <p id="artScore"></p>

    <script>

      document.getElementById("artScore").innerHTML = "success";

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

(I know extensions have different files for scripts, I'm going to put the scripts in a separate file once I get everything working)

I'm really not sure exactly how to go about this, maybe it's not even possible. But it would be great if I could get this to work somehow.

Comment: What kind of research have you done into web scraping?

Comment: @computercarguy I've done some. But from what I have researched, I can't do that in javascript. And I'm pretty sure Chrome Extensions have to use javascript. But maybe (hopefully) I'm wrong!

Comment: In the few minutes I've searched, I've found one web page that lists 5 JS libraries for web scraping, as well as another site that mentions using Chrome DevTools. Maybe you should spend some more time researching. Try Googling "web scraping javascript". The first few results should get you going.